# Formulation of $p$-adic Haar measure decomposition

Tags: measure-theory, haar-measure, p-adic, p-adic-integration

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}\DeclareMathOperator\vol{vol}\DeclareMathOperator\diag{diag}$Suppose:

- $F$ is a non-archimedean local field,
- $\mathcal{O} \subset F$ its ring of integers,
- $\pi \in \mathcal{O}$ : a uniformizer,
- if $e \in \mathbb{Z}^n$, I write $\pi^e = \diag(\pi^{e_1}, \ldots \pi^{e_n})$
- $d^{\times}g$ : Haar measure on $\GL_n(F)$ normalized s.t. $\GL_n(\mathcal{O})$ has volume $1$
- Same for the the Haar measure $du$ on the upper-triangular matrices $U_n(F)$ with $1$'s on the diagonal,
- $B_n \subset  \GL_n$ : upper-triangular matrices,
- $T_n \subset  \GL_n$ : torus of diagonal matrices,
- $f$ : an integrable test function in each case.

By Iwasawa, there is the Decomposition $\GL_n(F) = B_n(F) \GL_n(\mathcal{O})$. Since $\GL_n$ is unimodular, I know that there is a nice (let's say left-invariant) Haar measure $db$ on $B_n(F)$, such that $d^{\times}g = db d^{\times}k$, where $d^{\times}k$ is the restriction of $d^{\times}g$ to $\GL_n(\mathcal{O})$, so the integration would look like
$$
\int\limits_{\GL_n(F)} f(g) d^{\times}g = \int\limits_{B_n(F)} \hspace{1mm}\int\limits_{\GL_n(\mathcal{O})} f(bk) d^{\times}k db \qquad (\ast)
$$
This follows from the 'Quotient Integration Formula', for example Prop.1.5.6. in Anton Deitmar's Principle of Harmonic Analysis. Now if I pick $f = 1_{\GL_n(\mathcal{O})}$ to be the char.function of $\GL_n(\mathcal{O})$, then one has $g = bk \in \GL_n(\mathcal{O})$ iff $b \in \GL_n(\mathcal{O})$, and thus
$$
1_{\GL_n(\mathcal{O})}(bk) = 1_{B_n(\mathcal{O})}(b),
$$
and it follows by comparison that $B_n(\mathcal{O})$ has volume $1$ w.r.t. $db$.

**Question**
My question is now, I have seen in Cogdell's Lecture Notes on Automorphic L-Function (chapter 7) that $d^{\times}g = du \delta^{-1}(\pi^e)dk$ if one takes the Iwasawa-decomposition and decomposes it further as
$$
\GL_n(F) = \coprod_{e \in \mathbb{Z}^n} U_n(F) \pi^{e} \GL_n(\mathcal{O}),
$$
which I think means that (the author omits this part)
$$
\int\limits_{\GL_n(F)} f(g) d^{\times}g = \sum_{e \in \mathbb{Z}^n} \delta^{-1}(\pi^{e})\int\limits_{U_n(F)} \hspace{1mm}\int\limits_{\GL_n(\mathcal{O})} f(u\pi^ek) dk du,
$$
The author claims further that, if $f$ is left-$U_n(F)$-invariant, then
$$
\int\limits_{U_n(F) \backslash \GL_n(F)} f(g) d^{\times}_{U \backslash G}g = \sum_{e \in \mathbb{Z}^n} \delta^{-1}(\pi^{e})\int\limits_{\GL_n(\mathcal{O})} f(\pi^ek) dk,
$$
where $d^{\times}_{U \backslash G}g$ is the (unique) $\GL_n(F)$-invariant Radon Measure on $U_n(F) \backslash \GL_n(F)$, s.t. $d^{\times}g = d^{\times}_{U \backslash G}g du$.

It seems believable and intuitive to me, but I have not been able to derive it from my little knowledge on Harmonic Analysis. Can somebody give me a hint?

**My attempt**

For the first one I tried $B_n(F) = \sum_{e \in \mathbb{Z}^n} U_n(F)T_n(\mathcal{O}) \pi^e$, so by $(\ast)$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int\limits_{\GL_n(F)} f(g) d^{\times}g & = & \sum_{e \in \mathbb{Z}^n} \int\limits_{U_n(F)T_n(\mathcal{O}) \pi^e} \hspace{1mm}\int\limits_{\GL_n(\mathcal{O})} f(b k) dk db \\
& = & \sum_{e \in \mathbb{Z}^n} \int\limits_{U_n(F)T_n(\mathcal{O})} \hspace{1mm}\int\limits_{\GL_n(\mathcal{O})} f(b' \pi^e k) dk d(b' \pi^e) \\
& = & \sum_{e \in \mathbb{Z}^n} \delta^{-1}(\pi^{e}) \int\limits_{U_n(F)T_n(\mathcal{O})} \hspace{1mm}\int\limits_{\GL_n(\mathcal{O})} f(b' \pi^e k) dk db'\\
& = & \sum_{e \in \mathbb{Z}^n} \delta^{-1}(\pi^{e})\underbrace{\delta^{-1}(t)}_{=1}\int\limits_{U_n(F)} \hspace{1mm}\int\limits_{T_n(\mathcal{O})} \hspace{1mm} \int\limits_{\GL_n(\mathcal{O})} f(ut \pi^e k) dk d^{\times}t du\\
& \stackrel{k \mapsto t^{-1}k}{=} & \sum_{e \in \mathbb{Z}^n} \delta^{-1}(\pi^{e})\int\limits_{U_n(F)}\hspace{1mm}\int\limits_{\GL_n(\mathcal{O})} f(u\pi^ek) dk du,
\end{eqnarray*}
where in the last equation I have used Fubini, the fact that $t \pi^e = \pi^e t$ and that the measure decomposition of $U_n(F)T_n(\mathcal{O})$ forces me to take $d^{\times}t$ with $\vol(T_n(\mathcal{O}),d^{\times}t) = 1$. Is this correct? And if so, is there an easier way to see it? What about the passage to the quotient if $f$ is left-$U_n(F)$-invariant?